# Yii2 stateKeyPrefix for frontend and backend login

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I would like to login on frontend and backend with different credentials, from different tables, so I now have different forms, models, rules, etc ...

I tryed to set `stateKeyPrefix` as Yii had, but it does not work.

Anyone know how to login how I want to?

The following method returns true, because I am already logged n on the frontend;

```
public function actionLogin() {
        if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }
        $model = new LoginAdminForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        } else {
            return $this->render('login', [
                        'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should define stateKeyPrefix in user config:

```
'user'=>array(
     'stateKeyPrefix'=>'yourDifferentPrefixForEveryDomain',
     ...
),
```

And different sessionName in session component:

```
'session' => array (
     'sessionName' => 'differentSessionNameForEveryDomain',
     ...
),
```